# Redis datasource for spring cloud dataflow server

Tags: redis, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

As per the documentation, Spring Cloud Dataflow Service used RDBMS for storing stream/task definitions, application registration and job repositories. Instead of using RDBMS, is there a way to use Redis for storing this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDBMS is the default repository implementation for the Data Flow server core. You can still override this default repositories (**except** task/job execution repositories) by having Redis based implementations from your custom Data Flow server configuration. While you can have 'redis' based repositories for stream/task definitions and application registration, you still need to have RDBMS for the task/batch job execution repositories. That's the reason Spring Cloud Data Flow by default goes with RDBMS based ones for all.

Comment: Thank for the prompt reply. Can you please give me a pointer ( example/documentation ) to start using Redis repositories for stream definition and application registration.

Comment: We used to have Redis based implementations in 1.0.0.RELEASE: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/v1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/server/repository/RedisStreamDefinitionRepository.java You can use/customise those.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Let me try this out.

Comment: I was able to register the application in Redis. However I am not able to create the stream as the "Create" button is disabled in the UI and it's not asking me for the Stream name.

Comment: I have another question. How can I inject my custom implementation of StreamDefinitionRepository into StreamDefinitionController so that it can use my implementation.

Comment: I have opened a new issue for not been able to create new stream ( https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/issues/154 )

Comment: ok, thanks! for the custom repository injection, as long as you have the new custom StreamDefinitionRepository bean in your dataflow server that will get used because of the `ConditionalOnMissingBean` condition in the data flow server core

Comment: Thanks. I got the custom repository injection working but thenI could not test it because of the other UI issue that I am facing.

Comment: I was able to write custom implementation for using Redis as datasource for spring cloud dataflow. Thanks to @Ilayaperumal Gopinathan for providing useful link.